# change dynamic field value in logstash

Tags: filter, logstash

I'm using a filter in logstash. I wanna change value of a dynamic field in logstash.
I'm using below codes in my filter:

```
if [state_ls_keyvalue] == "False" {
            
    mutate{
        add_field => {"%{field_ls_keyvalue}" => "%{enrich_column}"}
    }

} else {
     mutate{
       remove_field => ["%{field_ls_keyvalue}"]
     }

     mutate{
       add_field => {"%{field_ls_keyvalue}" => "%{enrich_column}"}
     }
}
```

but it does not work. how shall I handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to ***type of field*** in elasticsearch. we can handle with ***mapping*** and change it.

using only `add_field`, the value of new field appends into old one.

using `remove_field` and then `add_field`, replace the value of new field to old one.

Answer (score 2):

Both [remove_field](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/0181745a993db5cd6f4e388c8544c0d4c149b7e1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/filters/base.rb#L201) and [add_field](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/0181745a993db5cd6f4e388c8544c0d4c149b7e1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/util/decorators.rb#L31) sprintf the field name.

```
output { stdout { codec => rubydebug { metadata => false } } }
input { generator { count => 1 lines => [ '{ "field_ls_keyvalue": "a", "a": "c", "enrich_column": "d" }' ] codec => json { } } }
filter {
    mutate { remove_field => [ "%{field_ls_keyvalue}" ] }
    mutate { add_field => { "%{field_ls_keyvalue}" => "%{enrich_column}" } }
}
```

will produce

```
"a" => "d",
```

If that is not happening for you then it suggests the conditional test of [validation] is evaluating to false.

Comment: Is the name of the field `source.port`, meaning it has a period embedded in the name, or is it [source][port], meaning [source] is an object that has a [port] field within it? Kibana and elasticsearch would refer to the latter as source.port, but logstash calls it [source][port] so that it can disambiguate the two

Comment: I found, It is related to type of field. I set mapping of considered field in index into string. It solved!